# NullPointerException for GoogleMap object

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` in my application for the `GoogleMap` object defined in the line:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I have map defined in my xml file like so:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

I also have all of the appropriate permissions as well as the API in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here is my entire source code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlaceMarker extends FragmentActivity 
    implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient = null;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_marker);

//      mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
//      Double myLatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
//      Double myLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();   

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude), 16));

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

//      Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//          .position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude))
//          .title("San Francisco")
//          .snippet("Population: 776733"));        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private Location getCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        if (location != null) {
            return location;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checkforGPSAndPromptOpen();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void checkforGPSAndPromptOpen() {
        boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!enabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    // Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity by Google Play services
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST : 
            // If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try to connect again
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    // Try the request again
                    break;
                }
            }
     }

    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Get the error code
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                errorDialog.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client finishes successfully.
     * At this point, you can request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        location = getCurrentLocation();
        takeToLocation(convertLocationtoLatLong(location));
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        String msg = "Updated location: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private void takeToLocation(LatLng newLocation) {
        if (newLocation != null) {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLocation, 16);
            mMap.animateCamera(update);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private LatLng convertLocationtoLatLong(Location location) {
        LatLng currentLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        return currentLatLong;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the Exception. Am I initializing `mMap` wrong?

Full logcat here:

```
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029): Process: com.example.MyApp, PID: 14029
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.p1/com.example.p1.PlaceMarker}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at com.example.MyApp.PlaceMarker.onCreate(PlaceMarker.java:52)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
02-05 01:08:49.122: E/AndroidRuntime(14029):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Comment: Please post your full logcat error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this

```
 mMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

With

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
    R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Try this.

Comment: @M D This works, but can you explain why I need to use `SupportMapFragment`? I have changed my minsdk to API level 12 and I am testing on an Android 4.4.2 device, so why wouldn't `MapFragment` work?

Comment: You must go to [Official Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapfragment) for further details

Answer (score 3):

In my case google map object invoke inside fragment like these & works perfect:

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;


int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if(sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
                else {
                    mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

> **Note:** The Google Maps Android API requires API level 12 or higher for the support of **MapFragment** objects. If you are targeting an application earlier than **API level 12**, you can access the same functionality through the **SupportMapFragment** class. You will also have to include the *Android Support Library*.

Besides using `MapFragment` you need to use `SupportMapFragment` as you are developing google map below the API level 11.

Write as below:

```
 mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                    .getMap();
```

Instead

```
 mMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I have my minimum SDK set at API level 11, so why would I need `SupportMapFragment` if I am not worried about anything under API level 11?

Comment: @Jack  Check out my updated answer. Please post your full logcat error. Its very difficult to catch your actual issue as you have posted one line error.

Comment: @Jack What is your line 52 ?

Comment: @GrlsHu I have updated the original post with my full logcat error. If I change my minimum API level to 12, will `MapFragment` work as it is or will I still need to use `SupportMapFragment`?

Comment: @GrlsHu `mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: Yes if you change your minsdk to 12 it will work but make sure you just do not change it in your manifest. You update it from the project properties. Check the documentation for more details which i have mentioned in my answer. @Jack

Comment: @GrlsHu I am not sure this is the problem. I have changed the minsdk to 12. I am also testing on a device with Android 4.4.2 and it is still crashing with an error on the same line. I have tried cleaning my project as well.

Comment: Have you added the support library and google play library in your project ? @Jack

Comment: @GrlsHu Sorry, I'm still new to Android development and I'm not sure what you mean by adding the support library and Google Play library. I have followed this guide: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. I have the `google-play-services_lib` project properly imported into my Eclipse IDE and I also imported the correct packages in my application. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, Please refer guide for set up of google map v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

Replace

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

with

```
FragmentManager myFM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
final SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) myFM
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```